# How to install Eclipse generated apk file on real android device

Tags: android, apk

I've developed a simple Android project on Eclipse. Then I export the application as unsigned application onto my PC. Then I copied the application on to the SD card. Then I tried to install the apk file by clicking on it. I also made ensure that I can install applications from sources other than from market. But my application while installing says that application not installed. I've tried one solutions in stack overflow which suggests to install AppInstaller and try from there. Even though it's not working.

What can be the problem with the installation?

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried adb install <path-to-apk> from your pc with the device connected. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to sign the app, because Android will refuse to install unsigned apps. The debug certificate will also work, but better create one even if you don't intend to release to Play Store, etc. In case you do decide to publish later, make sure you create a certificate with the required validity (more than 25 years), check the [guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode) for details.

Comment: Then why does Eclipse even have the option "Export unsigned application"?

Comment: So that you can sign it manually, or have someone else sign it with their key. Imagine working for a client who controls the signing key and Google Play account. You send them an unsigned APK, they sign and publish.

Answer (score 0):

After run a successful build ( Project -> Clean or Project -> Build All do the trick) go in your bin folder(automatically generated every time you build) and you will have an .apk file. Browse to that file in your Windows explorer (or whatever you use) and keep that folder. I eclipse show the ddms perspective  (Window -> open perspective -> other -> android/ddms) pick the file explorer, drag your apk file over there, and run it on the phone!

Answer (score 0):

You might be installing the app on the device which have lower OS version than the app supported version

Check `android:minSdkVersion` in you AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

And your device OS version